# Is there a way to run Chrome Extension without clicking?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I was going through the documentation for creating a Chrome extension. So far I learned that there are two ways to run the extension code, either using `browserAction` or `pageAction`. However, in either of these cases a user has to click an icon manually.

I was thinking of making an extension which can help gather user statistics and I don't want users to interact every time.

Is there a way to do it? What are the events which can be used in place of `onClicked` which will best suit this situation?

Comment: you are looking for `content_scripts` http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html'

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what kind of user statistics you are trying to gather, you could have a few event listeners in your background page. For example if you were collecting urls:

```
 chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
   doSomethingWithTheUrl(tab.url);
 });
```

If you are more specific about what kind of stats you want to gather, I can provide a more relevant example. Take a look at the available [chrome APIs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index.html).

Comment: i was looking for this kind of API only. Thank you :)